# How to extend the following proof to $n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis

I think I'm able to solve the following for $n=1$ (proof follows claim), but I'm not sure how to turn it into a proof for general $n$.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that for all
> $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$,
>
> $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{Leb(B_r(x_0))}\int_{B_r(x_0)}|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0$$

My proof for $\mathbb{R}$:

We wish to show that $\forall n, \exists R>0$ s.t. $\forall r<R$ we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $f$ is continuous, we know that for $n, \exists R'>0$ s.t. $\forall |x-x_0|<R'$ we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{n}$.

This means for all $r<R'$ we have:

$$\frac{1}{2r}\int_{\{x\mid\|x-x_0|<r\}}|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \frac{1}{2r}\int_{\{x\mid\|x-x_0|<r\}}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2r}\cdot2r\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Hence we can choose $R=R'$ and we are done.

Assuming this is correct, I am unsure how to extend it to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I did not have a lot of practice with measures in higher dimensions before this.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: the lebesgue measure of the set and the volume of the set as the integral of $1$ over the set coincide, so the same proof suffices.

Comment: @CSquared So I would just write, instead of $r$, $Leb(B_r(x_0))$, and they would cancel out just as the $2r$ do and that's it?

Comment: yup, applying the same integral estimate as well